# Why is $2^n > n^2$ for $n \geq 5$ only? Because $n=1$ is also true but $n=2$ for example not.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let me choose $n=1$ for my induction basis: $2 > 1$, true.

Induction Step : $2^n > n^2 \rightarrow 2^{n+1} > (n+1)^2 $

$2^{n+1} > (n+1)^2 \iff$

$2\cdot 2^n > n^2 + 2n + 1 \iff$

$0 > n^2 + 1 + 2n - 2\cdot 2^n \iff$

$0 > n^2 -2^n + 1 + 2n - 2^n \iff$ IH: $0 > n^2 - 2^n$

$0 > 1 + 2n - 2^n > n^2 - 2^n + 1 + 2n - 2^n \iff$

$2^n > 1 + 2n > n^2$, which can be proved with induction for $n \geq 3$

$2^n > n^2$, true by assumption

I have showed that, based from the induction basis, I can conclude the general statement. But like I have said in the headline the identity is not fulfilled for $n=2$, so something must be wrong in the proof.

Comment: Your work is very hard to follow, and certainly must contain some error since by the end you conclude that $1+2n>n^2$, which for large $n$ cannot hold since one grows linearly and the other quadratically.

Comment: I think you meant $2^n > n^2 > 1+2n$ for $n\geq3$.

Comment: If I would say it like that then the proof is right again alright?

Comment: No, the proof is not right.

Comment: You proved that the statement is true for $n=1$, and if it is true for $n\geq3$ then it is true for $n+1$. Can you see what's wrong with this?

Comment: Not fully yet because if I would Change the induction base now so that the induction base is greater than 3 and the identity is true, for example n = 5. How can I know that such an error like this would not happen again?

Comment: Because you proved it. You proved that once this statement is true for any $n$ that is $\geq3$, then it is going to be true for every other number higher than $n$. For the value $n=5$ the statement is true, so it will be true for all higher $n$. This does not work for $n=1$ because you require $n\geq3$ to use the induction step in the proof. Makes sense ?

Comment: PS. I suggest reading on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color , a similar and interesting problem with induction proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose $n=1$ as induction base, but the induction step works only for $n\geq 3$, i.e. you showed that $2^n > n^2$ implies $2^{n+1}>(n+1)^2$ only when $n\geq3$. That's where the problem is. Then you might try to use $n=3$ as the base case, but unfortunately for $n=3$ the statement is not true. That's why you will have to use $n=5$ as a basis case, and the induction proof will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously your inequality is not true for $n=4$

Thus you better start at $n\ge 5 $ which is proved the same way.

Comment: But how can I be sure that something like this won't happen again? I thought the induction is a General proof but if I choose n = 5 for my induction base, how do I know that for a m > n the property is not false again like it was now for n = 2,3 or 4

Comment: @RM777 From P(n) to P(n+1) make sure that your proof is solid and it works for  $n\ge 5$

Answer (score 1):

You have an error. You had $n^2-2^n+1+2n-2^n<0$, by in the induction hypothesis, you do know that $n^2-2^n<0$. But that does not mean that $1+2n-2^n<0$. It could be that $1+2n-2^n$ is positive, just not as positive as $n^2-2^n$ is negative so that their sum is still $<0$. The two will only always balance out for $n \geq 5$. But you assumed $n \geq 1$ in the proof. So go back and assume that $n \geq 5$, making your base case needing to check $n=5$, not $n=1$. This then makes the result the expected $2^n>n^2$ for $n\geq 5$.

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed for the **base case**

- $n=1 \implies 2>1$

and it is not wrong, then for the **induction step** $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ you have found that it works only for $n\ge 3$.

In that case what we need to complete the proof is to go back again to the base case and find a value $n\ge 3$ which works.

Comment: I realized that the proof is wrong but I understood why we can not choose n=1 as the base case

Comment: @RM777 What I mean is that it is not wrong assume at first n=1 for the base case, it works. The fact is that with the induction step we find that this works only for $n\ge 3$ then we need to go back and check the base case again for $n \ge 3$. Such kind of proof is fine.